# create half a pie with numbers on each slice in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create pie with numbers on each slice and showing only the top half of the pie so it looks more or less like this image:

[image]

My attempt so far is creating my slice like so: https://jsfiddle.net/xbou5704/

```css
.pie_chart {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip: rect(0 500px 500px 250px);
}

.slice {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    clip: rect(0 250px 500px 0px);
}

.pie.one {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.pie.two {
    transform: rotate(-70deg);
}

.pie.three {
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.pie.four {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.pie.five {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.pie.six {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.pie.seven {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.pie.eight {
    transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.pie.nine {
    transform: rotate(70deg);
}

.pie .slice {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.pie.one .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.two .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.three .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.four .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.five .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.six .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.seven .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.eight .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.nine .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie_chart">
    <div class="pie one">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie two">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie three">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie four">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">30</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie five">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">40</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie six">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie seven">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">60</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie eight">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">70</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie nine">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">80</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason my numbers are not showing, I am assuming it has something to do with `clip: rect()` in my css.

Once I get the css right, I will attempt to animate this pie with javascript so it rotates anticlockwise and dynamically display more numbers incremented by 10.

I am not too fussed about creating the actual slice visual. I just need the text to be positioned in the center of their actual slice as I will be animating the rotation of the text anticlockwise later with javascript.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you're duplicating the `background-color` property a bunch of times? You can simply set it on `.slice`.

Comment: try aligning the text to the center

Comment: Because I might look into having each slice in a different colour at a later stage

Comment: @Ahmed Look at the solution.

Comment: why not using SVG for this ?

Comment: Because I dont know how. Ultimately I dont care much of the actual slices them selves as i can always add a background image of the semi pie. I just need the text to be aligned in middle of their slice as I will then be rotating the text anticlockwise with javascript and increment by 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can make use of absolute positioning with tweaking around the values for top and left:**

```
.slice .text{
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:5%;
  left:40%;
}
```

to align the text in the slice container.

```css
.pie_chart {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip: rect(0 500px 500px 250px);
}

.slice {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    clip: rect(0 250px 500px 0px);
}

.pie.one {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.pie.two {
    transform: rotate(-70deg);
}

.pie.three {
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.pie.four {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.pie.five {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.pie.six {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.pie.seven {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.pie.eight {
    transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.pie.nine {
    transform: rotate(70deg);
}

.pie .slice {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.pie.one .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.two .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.three .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.four .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.five .slice {
    background-color: gold;
}

.pie.six .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.seven .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.eight .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.pie.nine .slice {
    background-color: #A7A9AC;
}

.slice .text{
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  position:absolute;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  top:5%;
  left:40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie_chart">
    <div class="pie one">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie two">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie three">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie four">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">30</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie five">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">40</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie six">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie seven">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">60</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie eight">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">70</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie nine">
      <div class="slice">
        <div class="text">80</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works, however the text appears to be slightly slanted. Any way I can fix the rotation of the text so it looks like the image I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ahmed Added a negative 10deg rotation on the text class.

Comment: Ok I think I fixed this by adding transform:rotate(-10deg) to the .slice .text

Comment: @Ahmed Is that all?

Comment: Well I guess this does solve my question, but if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, that would be great. Ideally I wanted each slice to be it's own container so all I would need to do to center the text in the middle of the slice is by adding text-align:center;

Comment: i would love to, but I am not sure where to begin

Comment: Well, for this I'd recommend you look up SVG Circle, path and text. But here's the basics to get you started: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_inhtml.asp

Comment: @Ahmed If it answers the question as you asked it, then you should go ahead and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the class text. If you add this:

```
.text{
  text-align:center;
  z-index:2;
  padding-left:40%;
  padding-right:60%;
}
```

It will make the text div appear on top of the pie slice and center the numbers on the divs. If you want to center them you can play around with the padding.

[Working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/xbou5704/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to undo the rotate on text otherwise the number will be wonky.

```
.text{
transform: rotate(-10deg);
text-align:center;
margin-left: -15%;
margin-top:1em;
}
```

see working [pen](https://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/GyrMRY)